# Where is the /runner/artifacts directory in awx on kubernetes cluster?

Tags: ansible-tower

I've setup a basic awx instance on kubernetes named *awx-demo*. All runs smooth so far, I can run templates with projects and inventories sourced from a git repository.

In the successful job log of a playbook run I can see at line 0:

```
Identity added: /runner/artifacts/74/...
```

Two simple questions: Where does the playbook run? Where can I find the **/runner/artifacts** directory?

What I've done so far:

From the Jobs log I see an Execution Environment *AWX EE (latest)*. That leads me to the pod *awx-demo-task-* and the container *awx-demo-ee*.

I connect to the container

```
kubectl exec --stdin --tty awx-demo-task-86d8b68cff-2l4c8 --container awx-demo-ee -- bash
bash-5.1$ ls -la /runner/
drwxr-xr-x 5 1000 root 4096 Jul 30 08:59 .ansible
-rw------- 1 1000 root   36 Jul 30 18:34 .ansible_runner_uuid
-rw------- 1 1000 root 4083 Jul 30 20:19 .bash_history
-rw------- 1 1000 root   20 Jul 30 09:52 .lesshst
```

I'd expect the artifacts directory here but it is missing.

In case the directory is temporary I found the environment variable and put it in the awx Job Settings section:

```
Extra Environment Variables
{
  "AWX_CLEANUP_PATHS": "false"
}
```

But still no artifacts directory.

Executing *ansible-runner* on a local machine works as expected. I copied my playbook setup to the tmp directory and run:

```
ansible-runner run -vv tmp --container-image=awx-rypox-ee -p playbook.yml
```

I find the directory tmp/artifacts/ and inside the fact_cache and job_events. Where is that same in an awx container?

System environment:

- awx version 22.5
- microk8s on ubuntu 23.04 in a virtual machine